# Unable to add PopOS's bootx64.efi as trusted UEFI file after updating to Insyde 5.34.1.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dual-boot, bios, acer

***System Information:***

- **Acer Nitro AN515-55**
- Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz   2.50 GHz
- Installed RAM 8.00 GB (7.83 GB usable)
- System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- Pen and touch No pen or touch input is available for this display
- **Edition Windows 10 Home Single Language**
- **Version 20H2**
- Installed on ‎16-‎01-‎2021
- OS build 19042.928
- Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

***Problem:***

To install Linux, I had:

1. Disabled secure boot and set a supervisor password Disabled fastboot
2. Disabled hibernate
3. Changed SATA mode to AHCI instead of "Optane with RST"

Everything was working perfectly and I could dual boot Windows and Linux.

But after installing the Windows 20H2 update and Insyde firmware update to upgrade the BIOS to 5.34.1.10 today, my PopOS (based on Ubuntu Linux) entry disappeared from the boot menu (which was opened by pressing F12 key). In fact the firmware update reenabled secure boot and fastboot and reverted to using RAID instead to ACHI.

I disabled these again, but the PopOS entry did not show up. **I did some research on the internet and found that one has to add the bootx64.efi file as trusted.** In order to do this one has to set the supervisor password. I have done so, but the "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" still remains grayed out. I also set the user password in the BIOS, but still it remains grayed out.

What should I do to access this BIOS option?

***The same question is also asked on the Acer Community forum:*** https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/636320/unable-to-add-popos-linuxs-bootx64-efi-as-trusted-uefi-file-after-updating-to-insyde-5-34-1-10/p1?new=1

Answer (score 0):

A user by the name "batmalin" **answered this question** on the Acer community fourm: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/636320/unable-to-add-popos-linuxs-bootx64-efi-as-trusted-uefi-file-after-updating-to-insyde-5-34-1-10/p1?new=1